# Weird Date parsing error in Java

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime, simpledateformat

While parsing a large number of dates in java, I occasionally get this weird bug :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".201144E4.201144E4"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at java.text.DigitList.getDouble(DigitList.java:168)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1321)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1793)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1455)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:355)
    at gameloop.tf2tradebot.user.UserManager.getUser(UserManager.java:102)
    at gameloop.tradebot2.bot.weaponbot1.Weaponbot1.onMessageReceived(Weaponbot1.java:269)
    at gameloop.api.steam.chat.ChatEvent.run(ChatEvent.java:49)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I this case, the date was

```
2014-12-13 06:56:27
```

The date format was

```
private static final DateFormat STANDARD_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

My code:

```
Date firstSeenDate = null;
try
{
    firstSeenDate = STANDARD_DATE_FORMAT.parse(firstSeen);
}
catch(Exception pe)
{
    pe.printStackTrace();
    logger.outputError(4001, "Error parsing first seen date. Shutting down...");
    logger.outputError(4001, "First seen date : \'" + firstSeen + "\'");
    CH405BotServer.shutdown(logger.getCallerName(), "an error in parsing first seen date");
}
user.setFirstSeen(firstSeenDate);
```

Source data :

```
isadmin = false
firstseen = 2014-12-13 06:56:27
lastseen = 2014-12-13 06:56:27
numtrades = 0
```

EDIT :
The string in the error log seems perfectly fine :

```
(ERROR 4001) Error parsing first seen date. Shutting down...
(ERROR 4001) Last seen date : '2014-12-13 06:56:27'
```

I need help on how to solve this.

Comment: It looks like you're just getting bad data - you're trying to parse a value of `".201144E45.201144E4"` which clearly isn't a date/time in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format. Unfortunately you haven't told us anything about where the data is coming from.

Comment: multiple threads seems to be racing to use same instance and messing up its internal state, is it the case ?

Comment: @JonSkeet I will update the post in a second showing the sample data.

Comment: Check where you defined `private static final DateFormat STANDARD_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);`. It should be before input data

Comment: @JonSkeet I get that, though that is sort of what I'm confused about. The input data is perfect.

Comment: @JigarJoshi It is possible. Its is a heavily multithreaded application. Are you positive this is the cause?

Comment: Yes it is possible, try to move the `DateFormat` to the local variable and try again

Comment: Or try to synchronize the use of STANDARD_DATE_FORMAT

Comment: [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html): *"Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally."* (It is very mysterious that `parse` could cause internal corruption though...?)

Comment: Is it possible for me to set it as volatile and continue to have it global?

Comment: @Hele no that doesn't help

Comment: @JigarJoshi I have changed the code to have local copies of the DateFormat in each function. But this is messy as I would have to change this is all functions each time the DateFormat is changed. Any solution?

Comment: You can replace `SimpleDateFormat` with [`FastDateFormat`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html) that is ThreadSafe, or find similar class in jodatime

Comment: @JigarJoshi So there really is no way around this but to use External libraries?

Comment: this is the lowest amount of change in terms of changing your code I see here now

Comment: If you have Java 8, [the standard formatters are threadsafe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: @Hele post the result here when you get chance

Comment: @JigarJoshi I have run the app constantly for the last 30 mins, so far, its going fine. I will ensure that it works well for a couple more hours and then close this. Meanwhile, could you kindly write an answer summarizing the info in the comments so that I may accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it is caused by race condition, `SimpleDateFormat` is **not** thread-safe and if multiple threads tries to parse Date from String to Date using same isntance it could mess up internal state of that instance

I would suggest either using local variable (warn: it is expensive to create this instance), so if you think it is too frequent, you can use [`FastDateFormat`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html) (thread-safe implementation of `SimpleDateFormat`) or as @Ray [suggested switch to Java8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: plus1 Thanks for that, I had a bad feeling this bug was due to a bigger issue.